# How do I change a vector into a single number

Tags: r, vector

Lets say I have a vector `x` which is

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

and I want it to have a single length of all the numbers in the vector so that the end result looks like this:

```
x = 12345
```

If I then want to example multiply it by 2 it would show: `12345*2 = 24690`

Instead of: `1,2,3,4,5 * 2 = 2,4,6,8,10`

Any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Another option with `Reduce()`

```
as.numeric(Reduce(paste0, x))
# [1] 12345
```

Comment: Neat solution with `Reduce`, +1!

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding thank for your reply. Actually I prefer your answer more. My post is just an alternative that may be less efficient. +1!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try

```
> sum(x*10**rev(seq_along(x)-1))*2
[1] 24690
```

or the variation by @Roland

```
> 2 * x %*% (10 ^ rev(seq_along(x)) / 10
[1] 24690
```

or define function `f` like below

```
f <- function(x, l = length(x)) ifelse(l==1,x,f(x[1:(l-1)],l-1)*10 + x[l])
> f(x)*2
[1] 24690
```

or play a trick with `paste` + `as.numeric`

```
> as.numeric(paste(x,collapse = ""))*2
[1] 24690
```

Comment: Your first solution is much better than any detour over a character string. A variation would be `x %*% (10 ^ rev(seq_along(x)) / 10)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nchar` and `cumprod` to get the digits, `rev` to reverse them and `%*%` to multiply and sum it.

```
rev(x) %*% cumprod(c(1, 10^nchar(rev(x[-1]))))
#      [,1]
#[1,] 12345

rev(x) %*% cumprod(c(1, 10^nchar(rev(x[-1])))) * 2
#      [,1]
#[1,] 24690
```

And for more than 1 digit:

```
x <- c(1, 22, 333)
rev(x) %*% cumprod(c(1, 10^nchar(rev(x[-1]))))
#       [,1]
#[1,] 122333
```

Answer (score 1):

using `paste` with `collapse`

```
as.numeric( paste(x, collapse=''))
#[1] 12345
```